cmake: separate multi-config build artifacts?
I don't quite understand the purpose and/or usage of the "Ninja Multi-Config" generator in CMake. When using it and specifying CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Debug;Release", the build directory will then contain build-Debug.ninja and build-Release.ninja. But when actually running e.g. ninja -f build-Debug.ninja, the generated build artifacts end up where they normally would without using multi-config. That means that if I first run the debug and then the release build the latter will overwrite the former! That seems pointless to me, in that case why not just generate one config to begin with? Is there a way to be able to build both configurations simultaneously in the same build directory?

"the generated build artifacts end up where they normally would without using multi-config." - What kind of build artifacts do you mean? Libraries? Or custom commands? Could you provide a small example project which demonstrates you observations?
